# Simple Zener diode circuit for UVLO

Tags: zener, undervoltage

Please see this circuit attached in this post/.

Basically, I want to build a simple UVLO CCT for my LED controller and I came up with this circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgNfz3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The RL in the circuit is a Voltage divider Load that is connected to my controller (ZXLD1370).

The thought behind this is that when the input voltage goes below 10V, the Vout will also start reducing which in turn will reduce the divider voltage and create a dimming function.
before using the LM4040-8.192 (d2), I was using a normal 8.2V zener diode. this worked well, although it had temperature issues. when the board was getting warm, the Zener voltage was varying and hence the controller was dimming before the board reached normal operating temp.
So I replaced this with a precision diode. Now the issue is that I can see the Input current reduce when voltage is below 10V, but then the current starts to rise again until the UVLO of the controller kicks in (7V approx).

what do you guys think I could do to solve this issue?

cheers
Labmat.

Comment: The LM4040 is not a zener diode- it is a complex integrated circuit. The behavior if you don't give it enough 'anode' current to regulate will be different from that of a simple zener diode. For example, it might oscillate. The start-up curves show overshoot.

Comment: So going by this information, that means Ill have to change the Voltage divider (R load) to draw the required Anode current right?
At the moment, the Voltage divider is drawing a few micro amps. therefore, would it need to be changed to draw a few milliamps?

Comment: Ok. I tried increasing the Voltage divider current. Now the circuit works, although I've got another issue. 
The cable into the DUT is a long cable and there will be a voltage drop across it (close to 1V). Because of this, if the supply voltage is 12V, the voltage on the PCB will be 11V (approx). I want the light to start dimming (i.e. the Voltage reference should start reducing when the PSU voltage is 11 or 11.5V = 10 or 10.5V on the board)